# Is this Pointer drawing correct?

Tags: arrays, c, pointers

is this drawing correct? if it's not right, can you correct me?

```
char a[] = "halli";
const char *s = "hallo";
char *t = NULL;
```

[image: pointer draw]

Comment: I'd not draw t's arrow since it is specifically not pointing towards anything. Begginers may think they can dereference t as the can dereference s when it is not the case

Comment: `t` should be something like a box with "null" written direclty inside of it, with no arrow.

Comment: Other conventions for what to write in that box are to strike it through diagonally with a line connecting one of the corners to the opposite corner. Or just write `0`.

Comment: thank every one of you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`a` and `s` are correct (as drawings go).

`t` doesn’t "point to" `NULL`, `t` *is* `NULL` (stores a null pointer value).

The memory map would look something like this (addresses are for illustration only, assumes big-endian representation):

```
Address    Item    00  01  02  03
–––––––    ––––    —–  ––  ––  ––
0x1000        a    'h' 'a' 'l' 'l'
0x1004             'i' 00  ??  ??
0x1008        s    00  00  80  00
0x100c        t    00  00  00  00
...
0x8000             'h' 'a' 'l' 'l'
0x8001             'o' 00  ??  ??
```

`a` is an array of `char` and stores the contents of the string `"halli"` starting at address `0x1000`.  `s` is a pointer to `char` and stores the *address* of the first character of the string literal `"hallo"`, which starts at `0x8000`.  `t` is a pointer to `char` and stores a *null pointer value*, which I’ve represented as `0x0000`.

While the *null pointer constant* (`NULL` or the constant expression `0` in a pointer context) is always zero-valued, the *null pointer value* used by the execution environment doesn’t have to be - it only has to compare unequal to any pointer to an object or function.

Answer (score 0):

There is no "null" that t would be "pointing" to.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).